# convert bumpbox(mootools) to use jQuery

Tags: jquery, mootools

I am looking to convert [bumpbox](http://www.artviper.net/bumpbox-demo/index.html) from using mootools to using jQuery instead.

Has anyone done this, or are there any guides out there for doing this, I am fluent in jQuery, but know not of mootools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BumpBox is a Mootools plugin and so to use it with jQuery, you have to port it.
Plus, BumpBox is a clone of [the original LightBox Plugin](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/#example).

Why couldn't you use the [jQuery LightBox Plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)?
Any particular feature that LightBox doesn't have?

Comment: I just love the effects that it has, also the fact that if the dialog is bigger than the window it will not shrink, I also love the style it has.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this jQuery port of bumpbox -> http://direseas.com/examples/bumpbox/. Maybe tweak it a bit to suite your needs.

@naveen: as far as I know [LightBox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) handles only images. It dose not support PDF and other content that the bumpbox does.